# Invalid address - solidity

Tags: solidity

I have a very simple contract as below:-

```
contract Test{
    address public creator;

    function Test(){
        creator = msg.sender;
    }

    function get1() returns (address){
        return creator;
    }
}
```

When I call test.creator(), I get the address back but when I call the test.get1(), I get an "invalid address" error message.

Can we not return addresses back?

Comment: It would be a good idea to accept the correct answer...

Answer (score 4):

You need to have your eth.defaultAccount set up , right now it might have been not set,due to the fact that get1() is a transnational method and it needs who is invoking it. The automatic public method accessor does not do that,thus you could able to invoke it without problem.

You can do something like  at the console.

```
eth.defaultAccount=eth.coinbase;
```

or

```
eth.defaultAccount="0xyoucaccount" // if you know your account address
```

This will solve the invalid address problem , but you would get another problem when execute the get1() method ,it would return you a transaction hash.

You have two options in cases like this, use event logging, or use a constant function. 
Pick your scenario.
This [Article](http://www.bullraider.com/ethereum/tutorials/342-understanding-invalid-address-error-in-dapps-or-geth-console) could help.

Answer (score 3):

Either call `test.get1.call()` or add the `constant`keyword in the definition of `get` :

```
function get1() constant returns (address){
    return creator;
}
```

The automatic "getter" created by the compiler for the public variable `creator` is "constant".